# An inequality about $a+b+c+1=4abc.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge0: a+b+c+1=4abc.$ Prove that: $$3\sqrt{a+b+c-3}\ge \left |\sqrt{a}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right|+\left |\sqrt{b}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right|+\left |\sqrt{c}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right|.$$ I try to replace $$a=\frac{x+y}{2z};b=\frac{z+y}{2x};c=\frac{x+z}{2y}$$where $x,y,z>0$ but it seems complicated and I didn't continue.

The following idea will help.
By C-S we need to prove $$3\sqrt{a+b+c-3}\ge \sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{\left |\sqrt{a}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right|^2+\left |\sqrt{b}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right|^2+\left |\sqrt{c}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right|^2}.$$
Or $$3(a+b+c-3)\ge \frac{(a-1)^2}{a}+\frac{(b-1)^2}{b}+\frac{(c-1)^2}{c}$$
Or $$2(a+b+c)-3\ge \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$
By replacement, it's $$\frac{x+y}{z}+\frac{y+z}{x}+\frac{z+x}{y}\ge 3+2\left(\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}\right)$$
or $$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)\ge 2(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{y+z}+\frac{1}{z+x}\right)$$
and it turns out $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\ge \frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{y+z}+\frac{1}{z+x}$$
which is easy by C-S $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\ge \frac{4}{x+y};\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}\ge \frac{4}{x+z}; \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{y}\ge \frac{4}{z+y}$$
Thus, we are done!

I have a question. Is the isolated fudging true ?$$\sqrt{a+b+c-3}\ge \left |\sqrt{a}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right|.$$
All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the isolated fudging is true.

**Proof.**

We have $a+b+c\ge 3$ and your inequality is equivalent to $$a+b+c-3\ge \frac{(a-1)^2}{a}\iff b+c\ge 1+\frac{1}{a}  $$
$$\iff a(b+c+1)(b+c-1)\ge b+c+1 \iff a+b+c+1\le a(b+c)^2,$$
which is true by AM-GM: $a+b+c+1=4abc\le a(b+c)^2.$

Hence, the proof is done.